# Java. Как отрефакторить множество if else чтобы каждый блок возвращал свой результат?

Tags: java

В этом классе есть макароны из if else. Какой код нужно написать, чтобы избавится от этих множества if else?

Здесь переменная inputData является входной строкой, которую валидаторы проверяют и определяют у себя является-ли строка эмейлом/ценой(за товар)/номером телефона

```
@Component
public class ValidateEngine {

    @Autowired
    private EmailValidator emailValidator;

    @Autowired
    private PriceValidator priceValidator;

    @Autowired
    private PhoneValidator phoneValidator;

    public DataType validate(String inputData) {
        if (emailValidator.validateData(inputData)) {
            return DataType.EMAIL;
        } else if (phoneValidator.validateData(inputData)) {
            return DataType.PHONE;
        } else if (priceValidator.validateData(inputData)) {
            return DataType.PRICE;
        } else {
            return DataType.UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
}
```

Enum class который в следствии нужно возвращать

```
public enum DataType {
   UNKNOWN,
   EMAIL,
   PRICE,
   PHONE
}
```

Comment: используйте hashmap

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста как использовать HashMap в данном случае, поскольку я не вижу как его можно применить. Спасибо.

Comment: Вам уже ответили, Вам еще интересен ответ с HashMap или Вы уже сами догадались?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если не сложно добавьте пожалуйста ответ с `HashMap` интересно посмотреть, спасибо)

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov позвольте я уже попозже напишу, отошел от стационарного компьютера

Comment: Anton Shchyrov ответил в полной мере в 1-м ответе (под словами "Например, так"), за что ему большое спасибо:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, так

```
public class ValidateEngine {
    private static class Pair {
        public final CustomValidator validator;
        public final DataType dataType;
        public Pair(CustomValidator validator, DataType dataType) {
            this.validator = validator;
            this.dataType = dataType;
        }
    }
    private static Pair[] validators = {
        new Pair(new EmailValidator(), DataType.EMAIL),
        new Pair(new PhoneValidator(), DataType.PHONE),
        new Pair(new PriceValidator(), DataType.PRICE),
    }

    public DataType validate(String inputData) {
        for (Pair pair : validators) {
            if (pair.validator.validateData(inputData))
                return pair.dataType;
        }
        return DataType.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

или так

```
public enum DataType {
    UNKNOWN(null),
    EMAIL(new EmailValidator()),
    PRICE(new PriceValidator()),
    PHONE(new PhoneValidator())

    public final CustomValidator validator;
    DataType(CustomValidator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }
}

@Component
public class ValidateEngine {
    public DataType validate(String inputData) {
        for (DataType res : DataType.values()) {
            if (res.validator != null && res.validator.validateData(inputData))
                return res;
        }
        return DataType.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

или так

```
public enum DataType {
    UNKNOWN(null),
    EMAIL(new EmailValidator()),
    PRICE(new PriceValidator()),
    PHONE(new PhoneValidator())

    public final CustomValidator validator;
    DataType(CustomValidator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public static DataType parse(String inputData) {
        for (DataType res : DataType.values()) {
            if (res.validator != null && res.validator.validateData(inputData))
                return res;
        }
        return DataType.UNKNOWN;
    }
}

@Component
public class ValidateEngine {
    public DataType validate(String inputData) {
        return DataType.parse(inputData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `HashMap`, такой способ отлично подойдет, если нет возможности менять другие используемые в логике классы

```
public class ValidateEngine extends HashMap<DataType, Validator> {

    ValidateEngine (
            EmailValidator emailValidator,
            PriceValidator priceValidator, 
            PhoneValidator phoneValidator) {

        put(DataType.EMAIL, emailValidator);
        put(DataType.PHONE, phoneValidator);
        put(DataType.PRICE, priceValidator);
    }

    public DataType validate(String inputData) {
        for (DataType dataType : keySet()) 
            if (get(dataType).validateData(inputData))
                return dataType;
        return DataType.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Другие способы ассоциации Вам уже подсказали в принятом ответе

UPD. Как любезно заметил многоуважаемый @PavelMayorov в комментах, если Вам важен порядок обхода валидаторов то необходимо устраивать обход не по ключам, а по значениям enum, это добавляет дополнительную проверку или необходимость завести валидатор, который вернет `unknown`

```
public class ValidateEngine extends HashMap<DataType, Validator> {

    ValidateEngine (
            EmailValidator emailValidator,
            PriceValidator priceValidator, 
            PhoneValidator phoneValidator) {

        put(DataType.EMAIL, emailValidator);
        put(DataType.PHONE, phoneValidator);
        put(DataType.PRICE, priceValidator);
    }

    public DataType validate(String inputData) {
        for (DataType dataType : DataType.values()) 
            if (DataType.UNKNOWN != dataType && get(dataType).validateData(inputData))
                return dataType;
        return DataType.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Comment: `extends HashMap<DataType, Validator>` означает появление кучи дополнительных методов в классе `ValidateEngine`. Оно точно надо?

Comment: Кроме того, вы изменили алгоритм - теперь валидаторы вызываются в неопределенном порядке.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, это самый надежный вариант, когда результат зависит от порядка, в вопросе речь не про алгоритм а про языковую конструкцию или рефакторинг, требований к алгоритму не предъвлялочь, в том числе ничего нет про порядок обхода..

Comment: К любому рефакторингу всегда предъявляется требование сохранения результата. У вас результат не сохранился: у строк, попадающих сразу в две категории, может поменяться классификация.

Comment: @PavelMayorov автор отлично знает что такое композиция а что наследование, для этого примера это не играет роли, вопрос про другое, хотя я думал сделать емапу членом класса, но не стал, чтобы сократит листинг оставив лишь существенные детали

Comment: @PavelMayorov захочет обходить в правильном порядке-будет обходить про values из enum, исключая unknown, кстати тогда почему Вас не смутил принятый ответ, там тоже изменен порядок обхода...

Comment: Потому что там порядок обхода фиксированный, поправить его на правильный дело недолгое. А HashMap принципиально не даёт никаких гарантий порядка.

Comment: @PavelMayorov для сохранения порядка можно использовать обход по values из enum, как я уже написал

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо за решение)

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov нет проблем, рад помочь